# Update all data in SQLite database?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I haven't found a good example for updating all data in your SQLite database.

I have a model class called `ItemDatabaseModel` that contains values such as `item_id`, `category`, `description`, `image_url`, etc. When updating a list of these `ItemDatabaseModel`s, I am currently updating every attribute one at a time but the end result is that all the data is overwritten with the last item that was updated.

Here is how I am doing my update. I start by iterating through my list of `ItemDatabaseModel`s that I want to update.

```
for (int i = 0; i < alItemDb.size(); i++) {
     dbProvider.update(alItemDb.get(i));
}
```

The `update` method that is being called accepts the model and then calls the `update` method for updating the database.

```
public void update(ItemDatabaseModel itemDatabaseModel) {
    mProvider.update(itemDatabaseModel, ItemSchema.CATEGORY + " =?", new String[]{itemDatabaseModel.category});
    mProvider.update(itemDatabaseModel, ItemSchema.ITEM_ID + " =?", new String[]{itemDatabaseModel.itemId});
    mProvider.update(itemDatabaseModel, ItemSchema.DESCRIPTION + " =?", new String[]{itemDatabaseModel.description});
    mProvider.update(itemDatabaseModel, ItemSchema.IMAGE_URL_1 + " =?", new String[]{itemDatabaseModel.imageUrl1});
    mProvider.update(itemDatabaseModel, ItemSchema.IMAGE_URL_2 + " =?", new String[]{itemDatabaseModel.imageUrl2});
    mProvider.update(itemDatabaseModel, ItemSchema.IMAGE_URL_3 + " =?", new String[]{itemDatabaseModel.imageUrl3});     
}
```

Then I update the database:

```
public void update(T model, String where, String[] whereArgs) {
    mDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
    if (mDatabase.isOpen()) {
        mDatabase.update(model.getTableName(), model.getContentValues(), where, whereArgs);
    }
}
```

From my observation the issue could be the `where`, but I do not know how to adjust it. Also, is there a better implementation for updating a list of new data?

Comment: You should update a single row based on the value's ID. There should be no need for multiple updates using multiple where clauses

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I need to combine the my where args. So change mProvider.update(itemDatabaseModel, ItemSchema.CATEGORY + " =?", new String[]{itemDatabaseModel.category}) to mProvider.update(itemDatabaseModel, ItemSchema.CATEGORY + " =?", new String[]{itemDatabaseModel.category, itemDatabaseModel.itemId, itemDatabaseModel.description, itemDatabaseModel.imageUrl1, itemDatabaseModel.imageUrl2, itemDatabaseModel.imageUrl3}); AND change my where to be the itemid?

Comment: I would suggest using `model.getContentValues()` for the update rather than a string array, but something like that, yes

Comment: Ok, let me try that! Thanks

Comment: @cricket_007 can you post your answer with an example? I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

For those of you wondering what the necessary corrections were to resolve this issue, here are the final changes.

Iterate through your list of items to udpate

```
for (int i = 0; i < alItemDb.size(); i++) {
     dbProvider.update(alItemDb.get(i));
}
```

Pass in your entire model so that you can later retrieve contentValues from it, and perform your update based upon an unique identifier (id, email, ect)

```
public void update(ItemDatabaseModel itemDatabaseModel) {
     mProvider.update(itemDatabaseModel, ItemSchema.ITEM_ID + " = ?",  
}
```

Update your database

```
public void update(T model, String where, String[] whereArgs) {
    mDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
    if (mDatabase.isOpen()) {
        mDatabase.update(model.getTableName(), model.getContentValues(), where, whereArgs);
    }
}
```